# Java - Program keeps looping, how to stop it?

Tags: java, loops

I've got this program working, but I have only one problem: it keeps looping itself. Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int type;

do
{
    System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println("1. Convert to a Letter grade");
    System.out.println("2. Convert to a Level grade");
    System.out.println("3. Exit \n");
    System.out.println("Please enter your selection: ");
    type=(1);                                                  // Put type in here ********************************************************************

    if (type==1) percentageToAlpha();
    if (type==2) percentageToLevel();
}
while (type != 3);
}
public static void percentageToAlpha ()
{
int grade;
String alphaGrade;
String messageOut;

System.out.println("Please enter the numeric grade: ");
grade=(78);                                                     // Put grade in here *********************************************************************

if (grade < 50) {
    alphaGrade="F";
}else if ((grade >= 50) && (grade <=52))
{
    alphaGrade = "D-";
}else if ((grade >= 53) && (grade <=56))
{
    alphaGrade = "D";
}else if ((grade >= 57) && (grade <=59))
{
    alphaGrade = "D+";
}else if ((grade >= 60) && (grade <=62))
{
    alphaGrade = "C-";
}else if ((grade >= 63) && (grade <=66))
{
    alphaGrade = "C";
}else if ((grade >= 67) && (grade <=69))
{
    alphaGrade = "C+";
}else if ((grade >= 70) && (grade <=72))
{
    alphaGrade = "B-";
}else if ((grade >= 73) && (grade <=76))
{
    alphaGrade = "B";
}else if ((grade >= 77) && (grade <=79))
{
    alphaGrade = "B+";
}else if ((grade >= 80) && (grade <=84))
{
    alphaGrade = "A-";
}else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <=89))
{
    alphaGrade = "A";
}else if ((grade >= 90) && (grade <=100))
{
    alphaGrade = "A+";
}else
    {
            alphaGrade = "Error - invalid mark, try again!";
}

messageOut=(grade + "% = " + alphaGrade);
System.out.println(messageOut);
}

// Conversion function percentage to level
public static void percentageToLevel ()

{
int grade;
String levelGrade;
String messageOut;

System.out.println("Please enter the numeric grade: ");
grade=sc.nextInt(78);                                                     // Put grade in here *********************************************************************

if (grade < 50) {
    levelGrade="R";
}else if ((grade >= 50) && (grade <=52))
{
    levelGrade="L1-";
}else if ((grade >= 53) && (grade <=56))
{
    levelGrade="L1";
}else if ((grade >= 57) && (grade <=59))
{
    levelGrade="L1+";
}else if ((grade >= 60) && (grade <=62))
{
    levelGrade="L2-";
}else if ((grade >= 63) && (grade <=66))
{
    levelGrade="L2";
}else if ((grade >= 67) && (grade <=69))
{
    levelGrade="L2+";
}else if ((grade >= 70) && (grade <=72))
{
    levelGrade="L3-";
}else if ((grade >= 73) && (grade <=76))
{
    levelGrade="L3";
}else if ((grade >= 77) && (grade <=79))
{
    levelGrade="L3+";
}else if ((grade >= 80) && (grade <=84))
{
    levelGrade="L4-";
}else if ((grade >= 85) && (grade <=89))
{
    levelGrade="L4";
}else if ((grade >= 90) && (grade <=100))
{
    levelGrade="L4+";
}else{
    levelGrade="Error - invalid mark, try again!";
}

messageOut=(grade + "% = " + levelGrade);
System.out.println(messageOut);
}

}
```

As you can see, it keeps looping itself over and over and over again in the output. I need it to simply do it once, and stop after that. Any help for a new programmer?

Comment: YOu are never referencing the scanner, sc.  So how can your type value ever change?

Comment: You never implemented the parts where those comments are, saying "Put ... in here", etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be hard coding the type variable the way you are. Generally inside of a while loop or in this case a do while loop you are going to want to increment some value. Based on that increment you are going to want to test for example

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 5) {
System.out.println("This is such a good answer");
i++; //central idea in the while loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you not change the `type` value in runtime. so it's keep  looping.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do
    {
    System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println("1. Convert to a Letter grade");
    System.out.println("2. Convert to a Level grade");
    System.out.println("3. Exit \n");
    System.out.println("Please enter your selection: ");
    type= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  

    if (type==1) percentageToAlpha();
    if (type==2) percentageToLevel();
}
while (type != 3);
```

and keep throws in your function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, your `type` variable is always set to 1. And your while condition is `while (type != 3)`. Since `type` is always 1, `percentageToAlpha` is called, and it never changes `type`, so it remains 1. Since `type` is always not equal to 3, you get an infinite loop.

If you want to get user input, use a Scanner. For example, in your code, this would be,

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in ); // use scanner to scan for user input
do
{
    System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
    System.out.println("=========");
    System.out.println("1. Convert to a Letter grade");
    System.out.println("2. Convert to a Level grade");
    System.out.println("3. Exit \n");
    System.out.println("Please enter your selection: ");
    type= s.nextInt(); // get what the user enters                         

    if (type==1) percentageToAlpha();
    if (type==2) percentageToLevel();

}
while (type != 3);
```

Comment: So do I change the condition? If s, what should I change it to? I want a 1 input to do the percentageToAlpha, and 2 to do percentageToLevel

Comment: If you want to get user input, use `Scanner`. Scanner scans for user input, and lets you do things with it.

Comment: This is for my programming class, I need to debug this program. It needs to accept an input, doesnt say where, and perform the necessary action

Comment: Sure. Which is why, to get user input, you can use `Scanner` (see code above), and the `nextInt()` method to parse the user input.

Comment: Okay, it's not looping but it's also not executing the percentageToAlpha or percentageToLevel

Comment: You're attempting to get user input in those methods as well. Use the same procedure - a `Scanner` and `parseInt` to get get user input just as we did here.

Comment: I have the scanner accepting grade inputs in both the percentageToAlpha and percentageToLevel, it's still doing nothing